# Java Fxml Table View With Checkbox

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, checkbox

I am trying to create a table view with check box.
For some reason, the method "initialize" doesn't run.
When I run my code, the table appears without the fields inside. the print message "TEST" isn't printed.
Could someone help me figure this out?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AddTransactionsToBlock.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
public class AddTransactionsToBlockController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TableSetterGetter, String> name;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TableSetterGetter, Integer> id;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TableSetterGetter, CheckBox> select;

    @FXML
    private TableView<TableSetterGetter> tableView;

    ObservableList <TableSetterGetter> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        System.out.println("TEST PRINT");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            CheckBox ch = new CheckBox("" + i);
            list.add(new TableSetterGetter(i, "HELLO", ch));
        }

        tableView.setItems(list);
        id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableSetterGetter, Integer>("id"));
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableSetterGetter, String>("name"));
        select.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableSetterGetter, CheckBox>("checkBox"));

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the controller linked to FXML file (e.g. with the `fx:controller` attribute)?

Comment: Don't add controls to the data - instead add a boolean property and use a CheckBoxTableCell to show/edit that property. Anyway, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.